# Entity Framework 6 database first date and time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I had a database with few tables. None of the table has date or time datatype column.

Today I created a table in database and tried to update the model and the column with date and time type didn't reflected in my model.

Searched on google and SO, most of them were code first solution.

Can someone please tell me or give me any link which will explain the reason and solution.

I cannot use that column if that is not pulled to the model.

Tried with renaming the column name as well but no luck but when changed the type it is reflecting in the model.

Comment: in the edmx designer try `Update Model from Database` and select the table with the new column

Comment: @Nkosi: tried so I got the remaining columns. only with type date and time were not reflecting